# Event based report in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the table like below

```
geofence  time   event    vehicle   
g1        10:00  enter    BMW
g1        10:05  inside   BMW
g2        11:00  enter    AUDI
g2        11:06  inside   AUDI
g1        11:07  exit     BMW
g5        12:00  enter    BMW
g5        12:05  inside   BMW
g5        12:10  inside   BMW
g5        13:00  exit     BMW
g1        15:00  enter    BMW
g1        15:05  inside   BMW
g1        16:00  exit     BMW
```

I need to make the report for how much time a vehicle was inside geofence , when it entered and exited

```
vehicle  geofence enter  duration     exit
BMW      g1       10:00  1 hour 7min  11:07 
AUDI     g2       11:00  -            -
BMW      g5       12:00  1 hour       13:00
BMW      g1       15:00  1 hour       16:00
```

**EDIT**
The vehicle can enter and exit same geofence multiple times and we need to find out the nearest exit from current enter event for the same vehicle. The vehicle emits data on every 10 seconds and sometimes we need to make a report for 1 week data which is like 24*7*60*60/10 data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my idea:
Group rows by `geofence` and `vehicle` 
Then for each *enter* find the next *exit* and then take the diff.

```
select p1.vehicle,
  p1.geofence as geofence,
  p1.time as enter,
  ROUND(time_to_sec(TIMEDIFF (STR_TO_DATE(p2.time, "%H:%i"), STR_TO_DATE(p1.time, "%H:%i"))) /60) as duration,
  p2.time as _exit
  from (select * from vehicle_event WHERE event = "enter" GROUP BY geofence, vehicle) p1

  INNER JOIN

  (select * from vehicle_event WHERE event = "exit"  GROUP BY geofence, vehicle ORDER BY id LIMIT 1) p2
    on p1.vehicle = p2.vehicle AND p1.geofence = p2.geofence;
```

Result:
[image]

**Note**: *duration is expressed in minutes you can change this to whatever format you want.*

Test Data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vehicle_event (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   geofence VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  time VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  event VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  vehicle VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));


  insert into vehicle_event (geofence, time, event, vehicle) VALUES("g1", "10:00", "enter", "BMW");
  insert into vehicle_event (geofence, time, event, vehicle) VALUES("g2", "10:05", "inside", "BMW");
  insert into vehicle_event (geofence, time, event, vehicle) VALUES("g2", "11:00", "enter", "AUDI");
  insert into vehicle_event (geofence, time, event, vehicle) VALUES("g2", "11:06", "inside", "AUDI");
  insert into vehicle_event (geofence, time, event, vehicle) VALUES("g2", "11:07", "exit", "BMW");
```

---

**Update:**

---

if a vehicle can enter the same `geofence` more than once we just need to find the next exit for each enter and put the grouping criteria after the join:

```
select p1.vehicle,
  p1.geofence as geofence,
  p1.time as enter,
  ROUND(time_to_sec(TIMEDIFF (STR_TO_DATE(p2.time, "%H:%i"), STR_TO_DATE(p1.time, "%H:%i"))) /60) as duration,
  p2.time as _exit
  from (select * from vehicle_event WHERE event = "enter") as p1

  INNER JOIN

  (select * from vehicle_event WHERE event = "exit"  ORDER BY id ) p2
    on p1.vehicle = p2.vehicle AND p1.geofence = p2.geofence AND p2.id > p1.id
  GROUP BY vehicle, geofence, enter;
```

**Additional Test Data Used:**

```
  insert into vehicle_event (geofence, time, event, vehicle) VALUES("g1", "12:00", "enter", "BMW");
  insert into vehicle_event (geofence, time, event, vehicle) VALUES("g1", "12:30", "exit", "BMW");
```

**New Result:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but some time same vehicle can enter and exit same geofence more than 2-3 times , in that case we need to find the nearest geofence exit time and if the data set is too big the query will slow down .

Comment: Sorry did not see your comment; it was weekend ;) please check if the update helps

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT vehicle as car,
geofence as geo,
(select DISTINCT timeEvent from test where eventName = 'exit' and vehicle = car and geofence = geo) as exitTime, 
(select DISTINCT timeEvent from test where eventName = 'enter' and vehicle = car and geofence = geo) as enterTime, 
TIMEDIFF((select DISTINCT timeEvent from test where eventName = 'exit' and vehicle = car and geofence = geo), (select DISTINCT timeEvent from test where eventName = 'enter' and vehicle = car and geofence = geo)) as duration
FROM `test` WHERE vehicle = 'BMW' AND geofence = 'g1'
```

Please note that I changed around the names a bit since you were using alot of reserved words (like exit and time). for a full list of reserved words check out https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-server-20-using-subqueries-in-the-select-statement/

P.S. There is probably a cleaner solution for the TIMEDIFF() but it didn't allow me to use references